# WebKitGtk2 load from string

Tags: webkit, webkitgtk

In WebKitGtk1 there was a [function](http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk/stable/webkitgtk-webkitwebview.html#webkit-web-view-load-string) to load an html page directly from a string.

> **webkit_web_view_load_string ()**
>
> Requests loading of the given content with the specified mime_type ,
>   encoding and base_uri .

Is there an equivalent in WebKitGtk2? I would like to display an HTML page that is re-generated very often, so saving it as a file and loading this file is no option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkit2gtk/stable/WebKitWebView.html

There are few load methods  e.g. webkit_web_view_load_html. Please pick up the one that suits your needs.